# Fijar una variable, despues de cumplirce una condicion

Tags: javascript, html5

gracias de antemano por su ayuda. Nesecito resolver un problema de una funcion JavaScript.

En el código que muestro a continuación pasa lo siguiente: Escribo y automáticamente aparece el número de caracteres que escribo dentro del input.

```js
function numero_caracteres(){

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var d = document.getElementById("cadena");
    
    var ancho_input= d.style.width;
    var ancho_i= parseInt(ancho_input)-6
    
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    var txt = d.value;
    var g= d.value.length;

    if(ctx.measureText(txt).width > ancho_i){   
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=g;
    }

    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=g;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cadena" value="0" onkeyup="numero_caracteres()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="0" height="0" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

El problema, cuando la condicional if de esta función sea true, la longitud de la cadena actual de input debe quedar fija. O sea, si sigo escribiendo el valor debe ser fijo. A menos que borre y la condicional cambie a false la función debe de devolver la longitud de la cadena.  Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me quedó claro lo que usted quiere decir con «*la longitud de la cadena actual de input debe quedar fija*». No obstante, encontré uno de los problemas que tiene su código.
Resulta que `d.style.width` está vacío, y es normal, pues este se refiere a las propiedades definidas en línea. Debería quedar así:

```
var ancho_input= window.getComputedStyle(d).width;
```

Luego la condición:

```
if(ctx.measureText(txt).width > ancho_i){
    //eliminar el último carácter, o lo que usted quiera decir con dejar la cadena fija     
    d.value = d.value.substring(0, d.value.length-1);
}
// fin de la función
```

Le sugiero que valore el uso del evento `onkeyup`, pues si deja una tecla presionada este evento no va a dispararse hasta que la libere; y al menos lo que yo hice dentro del `if`, puede fallar (si me paso por 10 caracteres van a quedar 9 de más, sólo elimina el último).

Créditos: [Why element.style always return empty in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645188/why-element-style-always-return-empty-in-js)